# SSIS 2012 C# can't recognize DTS variables

Tags: c#, ssis, dts

In my Script Component I want to access to variables. I do bellow steps.
- Drop Script Component
- In component editor add "System:PackageName" to ReadonlyVariables
- Open C# script editor
- change using to

```
using System; 
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
```

-add bellow line to Inpout0_ProcessInputRow routine

```
string packageName = Dts.Variables["System::PackageName"].Value.ToString();
```

but on Dts with red line I get "The Name Dts dose not exist in the current contex' !!
what should I do to recognize Dts?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks,I reach the solution as "string packageName = this.Variables.PackageName;"

Answer (score 4):

See this [blogpost](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.nl/2011/01/how-to-use-variables-in-script.html) with two ways to use variables in a Script Component. "Dts." is for the Script Task.